# Apache vHost and API "pretty url" getting 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite

I have a REST API that previously had urls on my localhost that looked like:

> localhost/api/v1/collection/resource

As I'm working on an API and web app locally, I implemented apache virtual hosts to get an api url of:

> api.mydomain.com/v1/collection/resource

I have a front controller that I'm routing calls. api.mydomain.com hits the front controller successfully. api.mydomain.com/v1 lists the directory (all the php files), which is a problem, and api.mydomain.com/collection/resource results in a 404.

My directory structure is:

```
/api
  /v1
    php files 
.htaccess 
Router.php 
index.php
```

.htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not quite sure where the issue lies. Anything other than the api.mydomain.com seems to bypass hitting index.php. I'm not too familiar with these rewrites, so any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. When I created the vHosts I copied an incorrect setting of AllowOverride None, which was rendering my htaccess files ineffective. Changing to AllowOverride All under the associated vHost directory resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.mydomain.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: No luck. Same result.